# SQL-Selecting specific values from a list

Tags: sql, sql-server

trying to figured out how to select an specific value from a list, so I have a label with a field like PSNO= Value but when I type a different value like 1575158 it always shows me the first value in the list (1136263) wont appear any other value but that one, this is my code

```
SELECT PSNO, PSLOT, PSPN, PSQRCV, PSDRCV 
FROM SIM400MFG.FLPKSLIP 
WHERE PSCO=100 fetch first 500 row only'
```

any idea of how I can select a specific value? Ty:)!

Screen

[image]

Screen and code

[image]

Comment: Show us db schema, sample data, current and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

 [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Right now isn't even clear what is the problem

Comment: SQL Server is mult-threaded and returns data in random order due to different threads finding results.  Unless you use an OrderBy you cannot get the data back consistently in the same order.

Comment: You seem to be using PSC**O** in your query. And there is no ORDER BY. Does this answer your question?